# is there a way to toggle search window results in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am not sure if this is a bug, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling eclipse but seems like the problem has been saved in cache somewhere. Whenever I do a file search or C/C++ search with eclipse (either by clicking on the icon, or by typing ctrl+H), I do not see a search window pop up with results.

Same thing when I right click on a term and look for references or declarations in the workspace/project. I only see the occurrences Highlighted in the files, but that means I would need to manually check each file, which is just not doable. I also tried resetting the perspective, no luck!

[image]

Results in highlights, but no result window on the right side like there normally is:

[image]

I do not understand why this happens, I wonder if I disabled the search windows with a shortcut, this already happened with disabling the breakpoints and it took me a while to figure it out. Is there a way to toggle the appearance of the window? And if it really is a bug, how can I destroy all of the program's cache, because uninstalling by itself didn't work, there was a few settings that remained with the fresh installation.

Thanks!

Comment: what happens when you open the search view manually (Windows->Show View->General->Search) before searching? Is it populated with the search results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in the Search Preferences:
Window->Preferences --> General->Search

Then the search view should open up after starting the search.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about that feature. I tried toggling it off/ back on but no success. That really seems to be a bug. do you know how to erase ALL eclipse data when uninstalling, so I can do a fresh reinstall without the bug?

Comment: Did you also try it with a clean new workspace? If that makes a difference you can start looking for a problem in the .metadata folder (or just live with the new workspace and migrate the projects there if that is feasible).

Comment: It worked with another workspace! I simply deleted the local repo and re-cloned it. Problem solved. Thanks a lot!!!